# Cocos2d-x smooth drawing

Tags: drawing, cocos2d-x, smoothing, cocos2d-x-3.0

i'm developing freehand drawing game, and the drawing isn't very smooth , i used this code:

```
void Canvas::onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)  {
    Canvas::drawEvenlySpacedSprites(touch->getLocation(),touch->getPreviousLocation());

  }


void  Canvas::drawEvenlySpacedSprites(Vec2 start, Vec2 end) {
   // begin drawing to the render texture
    _target->begin();
      float distance = start.getDistance(end);
       if (distance > 1) {
           int d = (int)distance;

           for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
           {
               float difx = end.x - start.x;
               float dify = end.y - start.y;
               float delta = (float)i / distance;

                Sprite * sprite = Sprite::create("brush3.png");
               sprite->setColor(Color3B::BLUE);
               sprite->setPosition(Vec2(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta)));
               sprite->visit();

         }
    }

   // finish drawing and return context back to the screen
 _target->end();



 }
```

I'm working with cocos2d-x V3.3

Please help me to get smooth drawing

Thanks

Comment: First of all you shouldn't create a new Sprite each time you draw it. Create it once in some init then reuse it. According to problem are you using some device to test the code or you run it on simulator?

Comment: Thanks,i use device to test, and in the cocos2d-x v3 you can't reuse same sprite, if you know how, please help me .

Answer (score 0):

As Nadarian says, you should not create a new Sprite each time you draw it.
Even though you cannot reuse same sprite, you can create sprite from same SpriteFrame.

First, you need to store SpriteFrame on some variable. Or, you can use SpriteFrameCache if you want.
I will show the code which will use SpriteFrame.

```
// create sprite
auto sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("brush3.png");
// get spriteframe from sprite
auto spriteframe = sprite->getSpriteFrame();
```

and on `Canvas::drawEvenlySpacedSprites`, create Sprite from the stored `spriteframe`.

Here is the example, change the this code

```
Sprite * sprite = Sprite::create("brush3.png");
```

to this code,

```
Sprite * sprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrame(spriteframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this implementation, I hope it will helps you: http://build-failed.blogspot.it/2012/08/freehand-drawing-with-cocos2d-x-and.html